# how to use graph in symfony2?

Tags: forms, symfony, gantt-chart

I make a forms of project I want to make gantt chart in symfony2. How can I make gantt chart in symfony2.3? Please give me suggestions.

Here is a gantt chart sample:

[image]

and here is my project table code:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block body -%}
<title>{% block title %}Projects>Create Projects{% endblock %}</title>
{% block stylesheets %}
<link href="{{ asset('styles/bootstrap1.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{{ asset('styles/uniform.default.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{{ asset('styles/select2.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{{ asset('styles/form-wizard.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
<style type="text/css">
.btn {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 4px 12px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: normal;
 line-height: 1.428571429;
 text-align: center;
 white-space: nowrap;
 vertical-align: middle;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin:0 300px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 border-radius: 4px;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
   -o-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;          
 }
 #space{
  margin:0 70px;
  }
.wizard-steps li {
display: block;
float: left;
max-width: 25%;
min-width: 20%;
text-align: center;
}
 </style>
 {% endblock %}
 <div id="fuelux-wizard" class="wizard row">
  <ul class="wizard-steps">
       <li data-target="#step1" class="active">
          <span class="step">1</span>
          <span class="title">Create <br> Projects</span>
       </li>
       <li data-target="#step2">
          <span class="step">2</span>
          <span class="title">Milestones</span>
       </li>
       <li data-target="#step3">
          <span class="step">3</span>
          <span class="title">Tasklist</span>
       </li>
       <li data-target="#step4">
          <span class="step">4</span>
          <span class="title">Tasks</span>
       </li>
       <li data-target="#step5">
          <span class="step">5</span>
          <span class="title">Teams</span>
       </li>
   </ul>                            
  </div>
<div id="space">
<h3>Projects creation</h3>
<form action="{{ path('projects_create') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <p>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> Next <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> </button>
    </p>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
  <ul class="record_actions">
    <li>
        <a href="{{ path('projects') }}">
            Back to the list
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
 {% endblock %}
 {% block javascripts %}
 <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-1.10.2.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $("form").submit(function(e) {             
         e.preventDefault();
         var url = $(this).attr('action');
         var data = $(this).serialize();
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: data,
         }).done(function( result ) {
            if(result.success) {
                $('#result').css({'color':'black','background-color':'#8F8','display':'Block','width':'200px'});
                $('#result').html('Projects Record Inserted');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#result').hide();
                    },3000);
            window.location.href = "{{ path('milestones_new') }}";
            }
         });
         this.reset();
     });
 });     
 </script>

 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Do you already have an entity to store the tasks? Will you enter manually the start and end dates of your taks? Or you want Symfony2 (with your code) to create the Gantt diagram from the input?

Comment: no i not enter the start date and end date of task,but i want to create gantt diagram from the input

Comment: First, you have to create the entity which will store your tasks. A [self-referencing table](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-self-referencing) should be good to store the dependencies between the tasks. Then you'll have to perform calculations in order to generate the Gantt diagram. At the end, you will have to display it. That's ambitious, good luck. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use javascript for this purpose, for example:

http://www.fusioncharts.com/goodies/fusioncharts-free/chart-gallery/show.asp?id=44
http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/
http://dansgreenshoes.com/2012/12/03/html-javascript-gantt-libraries/